# Roslyn: How to combine multiple project's compilation into 1 single compilation?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to combine all the compilation for each individual project into 1 compilation? I am currently working on a static code analyzer and hence, when for instance one method calls another method which is from another project within the same solution, there will be an error for me when i try to get the semantic model using `compilation.GetSemanticModel(SyntaxTree)`, as passing the `SyntaxTree` of a class of another project into the `Compilation` of current project will break my code.

Edit:
I thought of getting the references and syntaxtrees of each project and combining them, then creating a compilation based on it.

```
        List<MetadataReference> refs = new List<MetadataReference>();
        List<SyntaxTree> syntaxtrees = new List<SyntaxTree>();
        foreach (var project in projectToAnalyze)
        {
            Compilation compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

            var references = compilation.References;
            refs.AddRange(references);
            var trees = compilation.SyntaxTrees;
            syntaxtrees.AddRange(trees);
            //analysis(project, config, compilation);
        }


        var mycompilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test").AddReferences(refs).AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxtrees);
```

However, although I am not getting error for doing so, certain operations doesnt seem to work now. For example when I am using `SymbolFinder.FindImplementationsAsync` now, it does not return me with the implementations anymore.

Edit2: For example MyAnalyzer:

```
class MyAnalyzer {

    private Compilation compilation;
    private SemanticModel model;
    private SyntaxTree tree;

    public MyAnalyzer(SyntaxTree tree, Compilation compilation) {
        this.compilation = compilation;
        this.tree = tree;
        this.model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

    //Various override Visit functions for analysis
    public override void VisitInvocationExpression(node) {
         //
         //lets say i just pass the syntaxtree belonging to ClassB
         //into a new instance of MyAnalyzer
         MyAnalyzer newAnalysis = new MyAnalyzer(classB's syntaxtree, this.compilation)
    }
}
```

Code to analyse:

```
class A {

ClassB B = new ClassB();
B.method();
}
```

I run my analyzer by passing in the tree and compilation from my `Main.cs`, if assuming `ClassB` comes from another project within the same solution, then if when I try to create a new instance of analysis in `VisitInvocationExpression` there will be an error as `compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree)` will not work here as I passed the current instance compilation, `this.compilation`, into the new instance and due to `ClassB`'s `SyntaxTree` coming from another project. Hence, I came out with the idea of combining compilations into a single compilation.

Comment: Does the resulting compilation have any `Diagnostics`?

Comment: All of those collections are immutable.

Comment: That's a bad idea; different projects can have conflicting names or references or settings.  You should fix your code to work with the right compilation for each syntax tree.

Comment: Indeed, combining into one Compilation is not the way to go. There are several ways to walk between Compilations, depending upon what you're trying to do. I suspect your mental model isn't quite here; try restating your original issue with the context, and we can probably give better help.

Comment: take a look at Edit2, thanks for the replies! btw, is there any API in roslyn that allows you to get the compilation from the `SyntaxTree`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I had to my problem is that instead of combining the compilations into 1 single compilation, I did a try-catch block around the statement `compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree)`, if the compilation that i passed to the class does not contain `tree`, the `catch` block will loop through a global variable of `IEnumerable<Project>` whereby i store the projects of the `Solution` I am analysing and loop through the compilation from each projects to look for the compilation that contains the tree.